# how to use AWS Lambda function for HTTP Post Request?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ses, cloudmailin

I am working on AWS SES. I want to push the data on my server of all Receiving Email on Amazon SES. For this, I want to use the post method by lambda function. But not able to find out the solution. 
For this, I have found one solution which is www.cloudmailin.com. But it's also not working in .net. Apart from this is there any other way to post the content of all receiving emails into our database so that we can create support application.

If we can find the solution on Amazon, then it will be good.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're doing / what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to create a support ticket application using AWS SES service only.

Answer (score 0):

You can set rulesets in AWS SES to dump all incoming mails to S3. Then create a S3  notification to invoke a Lambda function and then when Lambda is invoked you can put the message to wherever (database or anything else) you want.

Hope that helps